# How to use react sortable js in custom component

Tags: reactjs, sortablejs

I have created a sample in react with 3 charts. I need to drag and drop each panel in using reactable js. I have installed the package and used the reactsortable tag to sort, but it doesn't drag and drop. Please anyone suggest an option to drag and drop using sortable js. I have attached the sample link for reference.

**Sample**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c94tmb-2y2eop

Answer (score 0):

use this package easy to implement and has a large community

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beautiful-dnd
```